# Delphi dbexpress SQL Server DLL versions

Tags: sql-server, delphi, dll, version, dbexpress

Are there any guidelines concerning which versions of the dbExpress DLL files to use with various versions of Delphi and MS SQL Server? Or is it always OK to use the latest versions?

I'm thinking in particular of the files dbxadapter.dll and dbxmss.dll.

The reason I ask is that I have one installation where access violations in these two files occur at seemingly random intervals. The app is compiled in D2010 and my client is using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Regarding the random AVs: is it a Terminal Server environment?

Comment: No it isn't a terminal server environment.